# When being in MERGE state is there a way to list already resolved files?

Tags: git

When you realize you did a wrong decisions during merge it would be good to list files which had conflicts, but already resolved. In this case you can run `git update-index --unresolve file` and fix it.

`git status` shows them as staged just as other files, which had no coflicts.

`git ls-files --stage` gives nothing because it shows only 0 version after resolution is done.

But there should be a method because when you run `git commit`, autogenerated message includes list of conflicted files.

Comment: Viewing .git/MERGE_MSG solves the problem, but maybe another method exists.

Comment: You can find such files with `git ls-files --resolve-undo`, which shows index entries that have "undo merge" information stored for `git checkout -m`.  But this includes files git resolved on its own, not just ones that had conflicts.  The `MERGE_MSG` file seems to be the only reasonably-permanent store of those.

Comment: Thank you! Valuable undocumented option.